# Octave Interpreter: "listdlg is not available in this version of octave"

Tags: c++, user-interface, octave

I've successfully created a standalone executable of my m-file with mkoct and it will execute the first few lines of code, including uigetfile where I can select a file from my PC. When the interpreter tries to execute the listdlg function I get the error: `listdlg is not available for this version of octave`

Inside `listdlg.m`, I can see this error is caused by `if (__octave_link_enabled__ ())` on line 150. This is not set when octave is started with `octave -cli`. It is set however when `octave --no-gui` is used which I think is what I want the interpreter to use.

So, my question is, is there any way of specifying through the C++ API how octave is started?

I'm using the following C++ code to run my script:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argvc[])
{
  string_vector argv (2);
  argv(0) = "embedded";
  argv(1) = "-q";

  octave_main (2, argv.c_str_vec(), 1);

  octave_value_list in = octave_value (argvc[1]);
  octave_value_list out = feval ("my script");

  if (!error_state && out.length () > 0)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "invalid\n";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you  need to execute a script just run octave at command line and ask it to execute the file `octave-gui --no-gui myscript.m`

Comment: @rahnema1 not quite what I'm after. I want to be able to use 'listdlg' in a script I've called with the c++ API so that it can be made into a standalone executable - being able to distribute it to other users that don't have octave installed is required. This is currently prohibited by the way the octave interpreter is started and I wish to know if it can be changed

Comment: The executable is not completely standalone it also depends on octave shared libraries .so /.dlls  and other programs (like perl for displaying help and ..) and other core .m files. Also if you can create an executable that can use `listdlg`  it also depends on Qt shared libraries. In windows octave is distributed as a zip/ 7z file and is completely portable. But in other systems I can not suggest a clean way.